# ¿Que significa el operador #define?

Tags: c++, c

He leído un libro guía acerca de c y c++, pero no entiendo la función del operador #define.
Al parecer es para definir pero no entiendo lo que significa lo siguiente "directriz de sustitución simbólica".
Gracias

Comment: En su forma ma´s sencilla, define un símbolo como equivalente a un literal. Por ejemplo, puedes poner `#define PI 3.1415926` y entonces en cualquier parte del código donde pongas `PI` es como si hubieras puesto `3.1515926`. De hecho, antes siquiera de que el compilador lo vea, hay un preprocesador que entre otras cosas hace eso, reemplazar todas las apariciones de las macros definidas con #define por su texto de sutitución.

Comment: Pero en una forma más compleja, `#define` admite "parámetros" que pueden formar parte de la sutitución resultante. Eso permite usarlo para escribir una especie de "funciones", que en realidad no son funciones porque el preprocesador se ocupa de expandir su uso (es decir, reemplazarlo por su correspondiente sustitución poniendo los parámetros donde corresponda). Por ejemplo si en tu código aparece repetidamente una expresión complicada, pero con diferentes variables cada vez, una macro así te permite simplificar la escritura, sin incurrir en penalizaciónes de llamadas a funciones.

Comment: Busca en tu codigo lo que este del lado izquierdo, y lo susituye con lo que esta del lado derecho.

Comment: Me gustaría aclarar que ese no es un operador. Las instrucciones que comienzan con # en C y C++ se llaman directivas de preprocesador porque el compilador previamente analiza el código fuente y es en ese momento que dichas instrucciones "se ejecutan". Para `#define` digamos que tienes `#define PI 3.1415`. Lo que hace el compilador es reemplazar cada `PI` por `3.1415`. Las otras directivas también son relativamente fáciles de entender.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ya se explicó con más detenimiento qué hace `#define`, pero me gustaría darte el ejemplo siguiente.

```
#include <iostream>
#define PI 3.1415926
#define PLUS1(x) x + 1
#define PLUS2(x) (x + 2)

int main() {
        std::cout << PI << std::endl;
        std::cout << PLUS1(10) * 2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << PLUS2(10) * 2 << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Si ejecutamos `g++ -E <archivo>` veríamos lo siguiente

```
... largo output ...

int main() {
 std::cout << 3.1415926 << std::endl;
 std::cout << 10 + 1 * 2 << std::endl;
 std::cout << (10 + 2) * 2 << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Como puedes ver, el **preprocesador** reemplaza los macros y constantes previamente definidos en dondequiera se utilicen. Por eso, `#define` se le conoce como *directiva del preprocesador* (en general las que empiecen con `#` como `#if`, `#include`, `#pragma`... son directivas del preprocesador).

Asimismo, como puedes ver, hay que tener cuidado con cómo definimos las directivas pues `PLUS1(10) * 2` daría como resultado `10 + 2 = 12`, cuando debería de ser `11 * 2 = 22`.

**Notas**

- El `...largo output...` corresponde a la cabecera `#include <iostream>`
- El manual de `g++` menciona lo siguiente sobre la opción `-E`:

> Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper.  The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which is sent to the standard output.

**Edit 1**

Como lo menciona Egon Stetmann. esta directiva ya casi no se usa en C++ pues desde C++11 se pueden usar cosas como [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), las cuales son más seguras pues se "resuelven" en tiempo de compilación, por lo cual también se pueden checar tipos. A diferencia de las directivas del preprocesador, que, como su nombre lo indica, se "resuelven" en tiempo de preprocesamiento y no es más que un simple reemplazo sin chequeo de tipos.

El ejemplo anterior lo podríamos cambiar a lo siguiente:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
constexpr double PI = 3.1415926;
constexpr int plus1(int x) {return x + 1;}
constexpr int plus2(int x) {return x + 2;}

int main() {
        std::cout << PI << std::endl;
        std::cout << plus1(10) * 2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << plus2(10) * 2 << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: me hubiera gustado que en vez de utilizar c++ usaras c ya que `#define` es una directiva antiquisima que proviene por herencia. En c++ hay muchisimas mejoras a esa keyword

Comment: @EgonStetmann. Buena anotación, muy cierto.

Comment: @EgonStetmann. `#define` no es una directiva propia de C, es mas, no tiene nada que ver con el lenguaje, es algo propio del *preprocesador* ni tampoco es un *keyword*, porque no forma parte del lenguaje.

Answer (score -1):

Se utiliza principalmente a una variable de forma constante.
El ejemplo mas comun seria el valor de pi, o el proceso de calculo para el radio de un circulo o cono. Se sabe que este valor nunca cambiara.

```
#define pi = 3.1415
```

Comment: Cuidado. En las directivas de preprocesador nunca se usa el =